# SELECT com LEFT JOIN com sucesso porém alguns resultados errados

Tags: sql

Estou precisando fazer uma `SELECT` usando 2 tabelas com `LEFT JOIN`, obtenho com sucesso a query, porém ela me traz algumas colunas com resultados errados.

Os resultados da Primeira tabela são:

**tbEntregas**

--ManuPart-----sum(Qtd)----avg(CustoUnit)----sum(CustoTotal)-----Count(Id)
---RC 018----------258--------------18.768--------------4939.70---------------43-----

Os resultados da Segunda tabela são:

**tbCustosProd**

--ManuPart-----sum(Qtd)-----avg(ValorUnit)----sum(ValorTotal)-------Count(Id)
---RC 018----------164--------------10.214---------------1694.81---------------9------

---

A Query com `LEFT JOIN` traz os resultados onde faço o uso de `SUM()` de uma forma estranha; ela faz a Soma de todos os campos onde o `ManuPart` são iguais (até aqui tudo certo), mas ela multiplica o resultado da soma com a quantidade de registros que existem do mesmo `ManuPart` da outra tabela.

Algo parecido com isso:

```
 Select sum(Qtd) * 
 (select count(Id) from tbEntregas where ManuPart = 'RC 018')
 from tbCustosProd 
 where ManuPart = 'RC 018'
```

---

A minha Query completa é:

```
 select entregas.ManuPart, 
 sum(entregas.Qtd),
 avg(entregas.ValorUnit), 
 sum(entregas.ValorTotal),
 sum(custos.Qtd),
 avg(custos.CustoUnit),
 sum(custos.CustoTotal)
 from tbEntregas entregas 
 left join tbCustosProd custos 
 on entregas.ManuPart = custos.ManuPart 
 and entregas.Qtd > 0
 group by entregas.ManuPart;
```

Esses são os resultados que obtive:

> entregas.ManuPart = RC 018 **certo**.
>
> Sum(entregas.Qtd) = 2322 **errado**.
>
> avg(entregas.ValorUnit) = 18.768 **certo**.
>
> sum(entregas.ValorTotal) = 44457.30 **errado**.
>
> sum(custos.Qtd) = 7052 **errado**.
>
> avg(custos.CustoUnit) = 10.214 **certo**.
>
> sum(custos.CustoTotal) = 72876.83 **errado**.

Comment: Mauricio, tem como disponibilizar o create table de suas tabelas junto com um insert data? Somente para recriar o seu exemplo e tentar replicar o "erro", do jeito que está na pergunta, mesmo editando ela, ainda está meio confuso.

Comment: Cria a estrutura em http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @MarceloBoni,
CREATE TABLE `tbEntregas` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ManuPart` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Qtd` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ValorUnit` double(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ValorTotal` double(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9997 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: @MarceloBoni,
CREATE TABLE `tbCustosProd` (
  `Id` int(1) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ManuPart` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Qtd` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustoUnit` double(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustoTotal` double(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2758 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: primeiro eu acho que a estrutura das suas tabelas estão confusas, por exemplo.. porque você tem uma coluna valor total? Se você tem a quantidade e o valor unitário, essa coluna pode ser calculada e não inserida numa coluna.

Comment: (continuando) Segundo, o que exatamente é a sua tabela tbCustosProd? Eu entendi que voce tem uma tabela pra gravar as entregas e outra de referencia para saber o valor unitario de cada produto (tbCustosProd) entao porque você tem CustoTotal e quantidade na tbCustosProd? Terceiro, por que você não utiliza como chave um numero ao invés de texto? Criei um Fiddle pra facilitar pra nós http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c59ee/3

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #tbCustosProd
(
    Id int NOT NULL identity primary key, 
    ManuPart varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    Qtd int DEFAULT NULL, 
    CustoUnit decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL
)
GO

create table #tbEntregas
(
    Id int NOT NULL identity primary key, 
    ManuPart varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    Qtd int DEFAULT NULL
)
GO

insert into #tbCustosProd (ManuPart, Qtd, CustoUnit) values ('RC 017', 1, 4)
insert into #tbCustosProd (ManuPart, Qtd, CustoUnit) values ('RC 018', 1, 8)
insert into #tbCustosProd (ManuPart, Qtd, CustoUnit) values ('RC 019', 1, 12)
insert into #tbCustosProd (ManuPart, Qtd, CustoUnit) values ('RC 020', 1, 16)

insert into #tbEntregas (ManuPart, Qtd) values ('RC 017', 5)
insert into #tbEntregas (ManuPart, Qtd) values ('RC 017', 6)
insert into #tbEntregas (ManuPart, Qtd) values ('RC 018', 10)
insert into #tbEntregas (ManuPart, Qtd) values ('RC 018', 11)
insert into #tbEntregas (ManuPart, Qtd) values ('RC 019', 15)
insert into #tbEntregas (ManuPart, Qtd) values ('RC 019', 16)
insert into #tbEntregas (ManuPart, Qtd) values ('RC 020', 20)
insert into #tbEntregas (ManuPart, Qtd) values ('RC 020', 21)


select entregas.ManuPart, custos.custoUnit, sum(entregas.Qtd) totalQtd, (custos.custoUnit *  sum(entregas.Qtd)) totalVenda 
from #tbCustosProd custos
inner join #tbEntregas entregas on entregas.Manupart = custos.Manupart and entregas.Qtd > 0
group by entregas.ManuPart , custos.custoUnit
```

=> [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/acf64/1)